# Notification number property not populated by stock apps

Tags: android, android-notifications

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html), the `.number` property of a status bar `Notification` signifies

> The number of events that this notification represents.

This works e.g. for Gmail (the number property contains the number of unread mails in the inbox), but for stock apps, such as the SMS or Phone app, the property is 0, even if the notification itself reads: "2 new messages from X" or "2 missed calls from Y". Should I file this as a bug in the Android bug tracker? I realize that apps are free to implement notifications (and set their properties) as they see fit. However, two messages from the same sender shortly after each other *should* cause this property to be 2, based on official documentation.